# Problems with Syncfusion GridTreeControl and Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, syncfusion

I'm new to  WPF and am using the Syncfusion Framework. I want to use the DataTreeControl to display a hierarchy of data which will be loaded and updated in a reoccuring interval. But for some reason it doesn't display the data.

Here's a snipped from my MainWindow.xaml

```
<syncfusion:TabItemExt Name="_tabItemTipps" Header="Tipps">                  
                    <syncfusion:GridTreeControl Name="_treeGrid"
                                        BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                        BorderThickness="0,0.5,0,0"
                                        EnableHotRowMarker="False"
                                        EnableNodeSelection="True"                                                   
                                        ExpandStateAtStartUp="AllNodesExpanded"
                                        ReadOnly="True"
                                        SupportNodeImages="True"
                                        VisualStyle="Metro"
                                        ItemsSource="SoccerMarkets"
                                       >

                        <!--  Code for GridTreeControl Columns  -->
                        <syncfusion:GridTreeControl.Columns>
                            <syncfusion:GridTreeColumn  HeaderText="Nation" MappingName="{Binding RoughCat}"></syncfusion:GridTreeColumn>

                        </syncfusion:GridTreeControl.Columns>
                    </syncfusion:GridTreeControl>
```

This the snippet from MainWindow.xaml.cs where the DataContext is set:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        SkinStorage.SetVisualStyle(_tabControl, "Metro");
        _settingsVM = new AppSettingsVM();


        _txtBetdaqUser.DataContext = _settingsVM;
        _chkSystemActive.DataContext = _settingsVM;
        _chkInSimulationMode.DataContext = _settingsVM;

        _mechanic = new TippMechanic(_settingsVM);
        _soccerMarketsVM = new SoccerMarketVM();

        Task[] tasks = new Task[1];
        tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await _mechanic.Init());//   _mechanic.Init();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        _soccerMarketsVM.SoccerMarkets = _mechanic.SoccerMarketManager.SoccerMarkets;
        _treeGrid.DataContext = _soccerMarketsVM.SoccerMarkets;
    }
```

My ViewModel (_soccerMarketsVM) is defined  this way:

```
class SoccerMarketVM : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SoccerMarket> _soccerMarkets;

    public ObservableCollection<SoccerMarket> SoccerMarkets
    {
        get { return _soccerMarkets; }
        set
        {
            if(_soccerMarkets != null)
                _soccerMarkets.CollectionChanged -= _soccerMarkets_CollectionChanged;
            _soccerMarkets = value;

            _soccerMarkets.CollectionChanged += _soccerMarkets_CollectionChanged;

        }
    }

    public SoccerMarketVM()
    {
        //_soccerMarkets = new ObservableCollection<SoccerMarket>();
        //_soccerMarkets.CollectionChanged += _soccerMarkets_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void _soccerMarkets_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Action.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Events for CollectionChanged are fired and I get the Console.Writeline output.
Does anyone see's something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

In GridTreeControl, you can populate the data using different ways.  In your code snippet, ItemsSource defined without specifying the Binding keyword and the MappingName is defined with Binding keyword. But for itemssource, you need to specify binding and for mapping name, you can directly assign property name without specifying binding. Please refer the below UG link of data population in GridTreeControl,

Link:

http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/wpf/index.html#!Documents/addingthegridtreecontroltoawpfapplication.htm

Elavarasan M – Syncfusion Software.